# Pass lambda as template function parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, lambda

Why doesn't the following code compile (in C++11 mode)?

```
#include <vector>

template<typename From, typename To>
void qux(const std::vector<From>&, To (&)(const From&)) { }

struct T { };

void foo(const std::vector<T>& ts) {
    qux(ts, [](const T&) { return 42; });
}
```

The error message is:

```
prog.cc:9:5: error: no matching function for call to 'qux'
    qux(ts, [](const T&) { return 42; });
    ^~~
prog.cc:4:6: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'To (const From &)' against '(lambda at prog.cc:9:13)'
void qux(const std::vector<From>&, To (&)(const From&)) { }
     ^
```

But it doesn't explain why it couldn't match the parameter.

If I make `qux` a non-template function, replacing `From` with `T` and `To` with `int`, it compiles.

Comment: First of all `qux` is not returning anything, so this should not compile `auto bar = qux...`

Comment: @nbro That has nothing to do with the problem at hand.

Comment: If you know so much you would not ask a question. Anyway, upvoted because I also don't know why.

Comment: Non-capturing lambdas are convertible to function pointers, not to function references.

Comment: @n.m. Unfortunately, changing the parameter to pointer gives the same error.

Comment: This is not the only problem...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A lambda function isn't a normal function. Each lambda has its own type **that is not** `To (&)(const From&)` in any case.
A non capturing lambda can decay to `To (*)(const From&)` in your case using:

```
qux(ts, +[](const T&) { return 42; });
```

---

As noted in the comments, the best you can do to get it out from a lambda is this:

```
#include <vector>

template<typename From, typename To>
void qux(const std::vector<From>&, To (&)(const From&)) { }

struct T { };

void foo(const std::vector<T>& ts) {
    qux(ts, *+[](const T&) { return 42; });
}

int main() {}
```

---

Note: I assumed that deducing return type and types of the arguments is mandatory for the real problem. Otherwise you can easily deduce the whole lambda as a generic callable object and use it directly, no need to decay anything.

Comment: Thanks! Prefixing the lambda with `*+` allows me to pass it by ref. Gotta love C++…

Comment: Actually, only `*` is enough, no need for `*+`.

Comment: what about assigning the lambda to a std::function and pass it as template argument?

Comment: @madduci If it's not strictly required, you shouldn't use a wrapper only because it exists.

Comment: @madduci No, really. If you don't need to use a `std::function`, using it won't make your code cleaner. It's wrong, that's all.

Answer (score 10):

If you don't need to use the deduced `To` type, you can just deduce the type of the whole parameter:

```
template<typename From, typename F>
void qux(const std::vector<From>&, const F&) { }
```

Comment: Yes, this is the recommended approach.

Comment: @DanielJour This has the unfortunate side-effect of having to go template metaprogramming ninja with `std::result_of<[…]>::type` to obtain the return type of `F`, which I need (and I have no idea how to do the template magic to get it). Also note that `*+` isn't necessary, `*` suffices.

Answer (score 6):

Correct me if I am wrong, but template parameters deduction deduces only exact types without considering possible conversions.

As a result the compiler cannot deduce `To` and `From` for `To (&)(const From&)` because `qux` expects a reference to function, but you provide a lambda which has its own type.

Answer (score 2):

You have left absolutely no chance to compiler to guess what is `To`. Thus, you need to specify it explicitly.

Also, lambda here needs to be passed by pointer.

Finally, this version compiles ok:

```
template<typename From, typename To>
void qux(const std::vector<From>&, To (*)(const From&)) { }

struct T { };

void foo(const std::vector<T>& ts) {
    qux<T,int>(ts,[](const T&) { return 42; });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're expecting both implicit type conversions (from unnamed function object type to function reference type) and template type deduction to happen. However, [you can't have both](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction), as you need to know the target type to find the suitable conversion sequence.

Answer (score 2):

> But it doesn't explain why it couldn't match the parameter.

Template deduction tries to match the types exactly. If the types cannot be deduced, deduction fails. Conversions are never considered.

In this expression:

```
qux(ts, [](const T&) { return 42; });
```

The type of the lambda expression is some *unique*, *unnamed* type. Whatever that type is, it is definitely not `To(const From&)` - so deduction fails.

---

> If I make `qux` a non-template function, replacing `From` with `T` and `To` with `int`, it compiles.

That is not true. However, if the argument was a *pointer* to function rather than a *reference* to function, then it would be. This is because a lambda with no capture is implicitly convertible to the equivalent function pointer type. This conversion is allowed outside of the context of deduction.

```
template <class From, class To>
void func_tmpl(From(*)(To) ) { }

void func_normal(int(*)(int ) ) { }

func_tmpl([](int i){return i; });   // error
func_tmpl(+[](int i){return i; });  // ok, we force the conversion ourselves,
                                    // the type of this expression can be deduced
func_normal([](int i){return i; }); // ok, implicit conversion
```

This is the same reason why this fails:

```
template <class T> void foo(std::function<T()> );
foo([]{ return 42; }); // error, this lambda is NOT a function<T()>
```

But this succeeds:

```
void bar(std::function<int()> );
bar([]{ return 42; }); // ok, this lambda is convertible to function<int()>
```

---

The preferred approach would be to deduce the type of the callable and pick out the result using [`std::result_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of):

```
template <class From,
    class F&&,
    class To = std::result_of_t<F&&(From const&)>>
void qux(std::vector<From> const&, F&& );
```

Now you can pass your lambda, or function, or function object just fine.